# How to make a list enjoyable to read?

Tags: style, creative-writing

I think [I'm a Modern Man](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/25390-i-m-a-modern-man-a-man-for-the-millennium-digital) by George Carlin, is a good example. And, after analyzing it, I've come up with some techniques.

1. Varying sentence length

> I’m a modern man, a man for the millennium. Digital and smoke free. A
>   diversified multi-cultural, post-modern deconstruction that is
>   anatomically and ecologically incorrect.

2. Using opposing ideas

> I’ve been inputted and outsourced, I know the upside of downsizing, I
>   know the downside of upgrading. I’m a high-tech low-life.

3. Using alliteration (or repeating the first word/word unit)

> ...laid-back but fashion-forward...super-sized, long-lasting...I’ve
>   been pre-wash, pre-cooked, pre-heated, pre-screened, pre-approved,
>   pre-packaged, post-dated...

4. Using rhymes

> I’m a rude dude, but I’m the real deal. Lean and mean! Cocked, locked
>   and ready-to-rock. I take it slow, I go with the flow, I ride with the
>   tide. I’ve got glide in my stride. Drivin and movin, sailin and
>   spinin, jiving and groovin, wailin and winnin...

Am I in the right path? Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks George Carlin was extremely annoying and unfunny? Refugee from the 60's. Bitter on life. Perennially anachronistic. Chronically awkward.

Comment: @Dean Corso I'm sure other people agree with you. But there's a reason why he's listed as one of the greatest comedians ever: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=greatest+comedian&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0CLcBEL8FKABqFQoTCMfa8MCAxsgCFWGppgodUuUIWQ&biw=1280&bih=938 And yes, he's was all what you mentioned. And he turned it into comedy. Which is genius, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking out '*[Skippy's List](http://skippyslist.com/list/)*', a modern classic of satire. One of the themes I see in it that's not on your list is **repetition**. List items will use a similar sentence structure with small variation, and these will be clustered together or spaced apart for greater effect. Using similar structure on items spaced far apart can act as a callback, and gives the list a greater sense of structure.

For example:

> 31. Not allowed to let sock puppets take responsibility for any of my actions.
> 32. Not allowed to let sock puppets take command of my post.

Another example:

> 124. Two drink limit does not mean first and last.
> 125. Two drink limit does not mean two kinds of drinks.
> 126. Two drink limit does not mean the drinks can be as large as I like.

The twitter account [WorstMuse](https://twitter.com/WorstMuse) uses the second kind, especially with one or two word tweets. It references repeating, over-used concepts or words, like: "Plucky orphans" or "Tragic lesbians" or "Retrograde amnesia". The snappy style lets the ideas speak for themselves, and the short format is itself a recognizable rhetoric structure.